# Lua Error: 'null is not an object (evaluating \'document.querySelector...).click\')'

Tags: docker, web-scraping, lua, scrapy-splash

I'm scraping https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/appartements and I need to click on a "load more" button so I used this Lua script:

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector(".DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s button").click()'))
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return {
   html = splash:html(),
   png = splash:png(),
   har = splash:har(),
 }
end
```

after clicking on "render" button, I had this error:

```
{
"description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
"type": "ScriptError",
"info": {
    "line_number": 4,
    "type": "LUA_ERROR",
    "error": "JS error: 'TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating \\'document.querySelector(\".DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s button\").click\\')'",
    "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:4: JS error: 'TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating \\'document.querySelector(\".DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s button\").click\\')'",
    "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]"
},
"error": 400
}
```

what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `document.querySelector(".DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s button")` returns `null`, in which case you are calling the `click` method on `null`. `.DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s` does not make sense: it matches an `<button>` tag inside a `<_1U08s>` tag inside a `<_1JgR4>` tag inside a `<b7ygi>` tag inside a tag with the class `DbXTC`. There is no such element, so `document.querySelector` returns `null`. `document.querySelector(".DbXTC button")` seems to work.

Comment: the class is named "DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s" so it contains spaces. but `document.querySelector(".DbXTC button")` doesn't work.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".DbXTC button")` seemed to work for me (it at least returned something), but maybe it's not consistent. `.<a list of classes separated by spaces>` doesn't do what you want it to. You can do `document.querySelector("[class='DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s'] button")` to find a button inside an element with the exact class attribute "DbXTC b7ygi _1JgR4 _1U08s" or `document.querySelector(".DbXTC.b7ygi._1JgR4._1U08s button")` to find a button inside an element with each of the four (space-separated) classes in its list of classes.

Comment: I tried many other possibilities but it returns always the same error `Lua error: [string "function main(splash, args)
..."]:4: JS error: 'TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating \'document.querySelector("div.DbXTC.b7ygi._1JgR4._1U08s > button").click\')'`

Comment: Okay. That JavaScript works fine in my browser's console. I don't know why it wouldn't work in splash.

Comment: how to do then ?

Comment: I don't have any ideas. You will need to find someone who knows splash.